# How to calculate bus route transfer by using pgrouting?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

Let say I have route 1 from A -> B -> C, route 2 from C -> B -> D,

how can I write SQL for pgRouting which can let me have the result route 1 -> route 2 when I want to get the shortest path from A to D?

Or should I just use Neo4j or other server side solutions in this case?

Comment: Can you explain this problem a bit better? Do you need multi-modal routing?

Comment: Excuse me, does multi-modal routing mean different transport means? If so, it is one of the case.

Comment: At the moment pgRouting does not have a working multi-modal function unfortunately. Multi-modal takes into account the time tables: https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/wiki/Multi-modal-Public-Transit-Routing

Comment: how you managed the bus route?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating dummy link over your city network to represent the bus route, then asign those link a different speed and can increase cost forr normal link to give preference to bus. Then you connect bus stop with city network and algorithm can change between different bus routes.

[image]